# Ruby: how to tag existing AWS VPC

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, tags, aws-sdk, vpc

I need to tag existing AWS VPC with custom tag for some purpose.

I found out how to tag VPC when creating it, but nothing about tagging existing VPC.

Objects that I have at disposal in existing code are EC2, RDS and autoscaling groups (and their attributes of course), so instead tagging all instances and RDSs, I would like to tag their VPC.

edit: got it, here it is if someone needs it, I filter VPCs by environment tag ('tag:environment') and environment_filter_list contains full name of environment(s) e.g. dev01-eu-west-1

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1', retry_limit: 10, retry_jitter: :full, retry_base_delay: 5)

vpc_response = ec2.describe_vpcs(filters:[{ name: 'tag:environment', values: environment_filter_list }])

vpc_id = vpc_response.data.vpcs[0].vpc_id

#when you have multiple environments in filter list, you should instead of previous line iterate like this and put tag for each vpc id in vpc_hash:
    #vpc_hash = {}
    #vpc_response.data.vpcs.each do |vpc|
      #vpc_name = name_from_tag(vpc)
      #vpc_hash[vpc.vpc_id] = vpc_name if vpc_name
    #end

resp = ec2.create_tags({
  resources: [
    vpc_id,
  ],
  tags: [
    {
      key: "StopDate",
      value: "20190321",
    },
  ],
})
```